# java reading from a file from a certain point to another

Tags: java, file

This is my first question here, I hope you kind sirs can help me and I thank you in advance.

I am trying to write a Java project using threads and the replicated workers paradigm.  What I want to do is create a workpool of tasks.  The tasks that the workers have to do is simply count the number of words in a specified file between two indices. I want to create a task like this: (file,startIndex,finishIndex).  I have problems finding out what file handling class I should use to open a file and read the words from startIndex to finishIndex.  I should also mention that I am given a chunk size and I am supposed to split the tasks using that.  ChunkSize is an int representing the number of bytes

Bottom line: I want to read from a file from startIndex to startIndex + chunkSize.

Comment: You need to drill down to a specific question.

Comment: Want to know what class can help me to read from a file in the way described.Example : file1.txt contains : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rhoncus neque vel justo dapibus condimentum. Pellentesque habitant."      I want to read from the 50th byte to 100th byte from this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class. It has a "seek" method that allows you to skip to a certain position in the file. Example:

```
int chunkSize = 64;
long startingIndex = 55;
byte[] bytesRead = new byte[chunkSize];

RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt", "r");
file.seek(startingIndex);
file.read(bytesRead);
file.close();
```

Note that this will seek a number of *bytes*, not words. It's impossible to know where are the words in a file before reading it. Counting the spaces and adding one is a naive method that would work well in this case.

Comment: Yeah.RandomAccesFile should do the work.I am currently trying it out and should do the trick for what i want.Thank you very much for the help